# Export mac osx keyboard shortcuts to file?

Tags: macos, ms-office, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm changing from PC to Mac and I find that the keyboard shortcuts on Word are very different. I know I can change the shortcuts in preferences but I wonder if it's possible to export these settings and later import them.

If that's possible, maybe someone has already done that and share such settings?